# Can I square the triangle?

Tags: galois-theory, triangles, area, geometric-construction

I know I can't construct a square with the same area as a given circle (because $\pi$ is transcendental).

Can I construct (ruler and compass) a square with the same area as a given triangle?
[image]

I think I can because [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation) only includes a radical (order 2) so it should be constructable. However, I'm not sure because some of the terms under the radical (when expanded out) are of degree 4. Does the fact that they are under the radical and hence 'really' of degree 2 importance help?

> Heron's formula:
>
> $$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \frac14\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 - 2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$$

Comment: as 4 is a power of 2 I don't think it matters.

Comment: You don't need Heron's formula.

Comment: More strongly, we can use straightedge and compass to cut up the triangle into a finite number of triangles and reassemble the pieces to form a square.  Please see the Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem.

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36628/285185

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Two steps:

(1) Since the area of the triangle
is half the area of a rectangle
with the same base and altitude,
construct a rectangle
with the same area as the triangle.

(2) Euclid knew how to
construct a square with
the same area as a given rectangle.
Look it up.

Answer (score 2):

See construction number 12 [on the page linked here.](http://web.csulb.edu/~saleem/Course-F08-310/Constructions.pdf)

A summary of the construction is:

Drop a perpendicular from one vertex of the triangle to the opposite side.
You now have a base $b$ and altitude $h$ of the triangle,
so the area of the triangle is $\frac12 bh$.

Find the geometric mean of $b$ and $h$, that is, construct 
a segment of length $\sqrt{bh}$.

Construct a square of side $\sqrt{bh}$. Its area is $bh$.

Join the midpoints of all four sides of the square with segments,
forming a smaller square.
This square's area is $\frac12 bh$, as desired.

Comment: For the last step, draw the diagonals of the square. They intersect in its center, and the distance from the center to any corner is the length of the desired square.

Comment: @martycohen Yes, that works too, and has the nice feature that you get two adjacent sides of the square just by using the straightedge twice. But the basic idea in either case is to construct a square whose diagonal equals the side of the original square.